# Is there any interpretation to the imaginary component obtained when computing the geometric mean of a series of negative returns?

Tags: complex-numbers, finance

When computing returns in finance geometric means are used because the return time series of a financial asset is a geometric series: $\mu_r = \sqrt[T]{\prod_{t=1}^T r_t}$ where the return is computed as $r_t = \log\left(\frac{p_{t+1}}{p_t}\right)$ and $p$ is the value of the asset. Negative returns are (sadly) a financial reality. But the geometric mean return obtained when there are negative returns does not lend itself to a straightforward interpretation because $r < 0 \implies \mu_r \notin \mathbb{R} $.
Is there any financial interpretation to the imaginary component obtained when computing the geometric mean of a return time series (geometric series) including negative returns?

Comment: It seems surprising that $r_t$ is computed with a $\log$ and then you take a geometric mean of the logs.  If you don't take the log, you have $r_t=\frac{p_{t+1}}{p_t}$ and over $k$ years the total return is just $\frac{p_{t+k}}{p_t}$.  Then taking the geometric mean gives the annual return that if it were repeated $k$ times would give the observed return.  Now when you have a loss the value you multiply is positive (though less than $1$) and taking the geometric mean makes sense.

Comment: Sorry about the subscript; I missed that in the $\LaTeX$.

Comment: You should be taking the arithmetic mean of the logs of the price ratios, or the geometric mean of the actual price ratios ($p_{t+1}/p_t$), to determine the annualized (average) return.  I don't think the geometric mean of the log-ratios is meaningful (or, indeed, actually used to compute returns in finance).

Comment: This clarifies things a lot. Perhaps you could make that an answer. However now I am a little confused about the relationship between discrete versus continuous returns and arithmetic versus geometric series and means...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the logarithmic values, then you will get the log of the geometric mean by calculating $$log(\mu_r)=\frac{1}{T} \cdot \sum_{t=1}^T r_t$$

The formula you have posted is only valid for returns, which have not been logarithmized.